# Android Studio XML doesn't show anything in Design View. (empty screen)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, androiddesignsupport

I checked other questions, but they all are about blank screen(white screen or theme). But in my case, it shows literally nothing.

I tried 'Force Refresh Layout'. But It didn't work. And only reboot can solve problem. just closing and opening Android Studio doesn't solve this problem(I even tried with removing cache and restart.)

Which one of Android Studio is related to Design View? I don't want to reboot and even though I reboot, this problem keep occurring, So, I need some better way to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: change the theme and force refresh the layout

Comment: in root constraintLayout change `android:layoutHeight:wrap_content` to `android:layoutHeight:match_parent`

Comment: It's very old question. but for someone who is suffering the same problem. I think I solved it by solving the warnings(the yellow ones)

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution and see if any one actually works

1. Update your constraint layout dependency
   change the dependencies in your gradle module file to something like this Specially and sync it **implementation'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

2. Invalidate Cache/restart
   **File>Invalidate Cache/restart**
3. Disable and Enable android support apk
   **File>Settings>plugins>Under Installed section -> disable and enable and see if it works**

Comment: Tried all of the above, still not rendering anything, only for some views, and those views did work previously

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to see if you use any Theme.AppCompat theme to your constraint layout. For example

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```